# Salesforce how to make a checkbox turn to false in two days

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am calling a future class where an email is sent to the customer, a checkbox is turned into TRUE to avoid duplication. The email is triggered when a subscriber's end date is 15 days before.

Now this is a subscription renewal situation and the user subscribes and again continues the package. But when the renewal arrives before 15 days again, this checkbox is true so my logic would overlook this account.

How can I turn this checkbox to false again  after 2 days so that this email is again triggered.?

Note this check box is not read only and I would want this to be turning to true when the next iteration of expiry comes up.

How can I achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a date field on the object you are setting the checkbox on and set this in your email class (or where you call the class from eg Process builder) to be 2 days in the future. You could then have the checkbox as a formula field such as *TODAY() < plusTwoDaysField__c* then when 2 days had passed the formula would evaluate to false until you set the date field to be 2 days in the future again. Hope that helps